# Chrome Extension: Center Created Window on Icon Click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

### Requiring

**First**: Click on the Extension Icon in the toolbar to open a newly Created Window.

**Second**: Set Position of the Created Window on the Screen.

**Third**: The Created Window Loads "WebContent/index.html"

### Current Extension Settings

Manifest Version: **v3**

### Issue

I'm having issues migrating the below code to manifest version 3 from version 2, and I'm not able to get the screen width/height to center the window by using window.screen.width, is there another way?

### Code Using

```
//Manifest Version 2
  let ftdWindow = null;

  chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(wind => {
    console.log(`browserAction.onClicked`);
    if (ftdWindow) {
        console.log("The window exists!");
        let info = {
            focused: true
        };
        chrome.windows.update(ftdWindow.id, info, (w) => {
            if (!w) {
                console.log(`Error: The window does not exist!`);
                ftdWindow = null;
            }
        });
    } else {
        chrome.storage.sync.get(['windowSize'], function(result) {
            console.log(`storage.sync`);
            let width = 1000;
            let height = 700;
            if (result.windowSize) {
                width = parseInt(result.windowSize.width);
                height = parseInt(result.windowSize.height);
            }
            let left = parseInt((window.screen.width - width) / 2);
            let top = parseInt((window.screen.height - height) / 2);
            chrome.windows.create({
                url: chrome.runtime.getURL("WebContent/index.html"),
                type: "panel",
                left, top, width, height
            }, function(window) {
                ftdWindow = window;
            });
        });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

```
//manifest.json
"permissions": [
      "storage",
      "unlimitedStorage",
      "system.display"
]
```

```
//Manifest Version 3 - background.js
let ftdWindow = null;

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(wind => {
  console.log('Action.onClicked',ftdWindow);
    if (ftdWindow) {
        console.log("The window exists!");
        let info = {
            focused: true
        };
        chrome.windows.update(ftdWindow.id, info, (w) => {
            if (!w) {
                console.log(`Error: The window does not exist!`);
                ftdWindow = null;
            }
        });
    }else{
        console.log("The window does not exist!");
        chrome.storage.local.get("windowSize", (result) => {
            let width = 1000;
            let height = 700;
            if (result.windowSize) {
                width = result.windowSize.width;
                height = result.windowSize.height;
            }

            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                chrome.system.display.getInfo((displayInfo)=>{
                    resolve(displayInfo);
                });
            }).then((result)=>{
                result.forEach((display) => {
                    if(display.isPrimary){
                        let left = parseInt((display.bounds.width - width) / 2);
                        let top = parseInt((display.bounds.height - height) / 2);
                        
                        chrome.windows.create({
                            url: chrome.runtime.getURL("WebContent/index.html"),
                            type: "panel",
                            left, top, width, height
                        }, function(window) {
                            ftdWindow = window;
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        })
    }
});
```

### Additional Code - main.js

This will allow you to save the height/width of the window on resize for use in the above code.

```
window.onresize = function() {
    chrome.storage.local.set({
      windowSize: {
        height: Math.max(window.outerHeight, 300),
        width: Math.max(window.outerWidth, 400)
      }
    });
}
```